# Cannot access the file created by my app

Tags: android

I have the following block of code in my program. It creates a folder and a simple csv file. The file can successfully be created, by using ASTRO, I am sure the file and folder are created, but when I connect the device to my desktop, I cannot find the folder nor the file, what can I do to make them accessible in my desktop? The device I am using is Galaxy Nexus.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Chico");
if(!folder.exists()){
    folder.mkdir();
}
final String record = folder.toString() + "/" + "record.csv";
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
            try{
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(record);
                fw.append("ClientName");
                fw.append(',');
                fw.append("SiteName");
                fw.append(',');
                fw.append("Type");
                fw.append(',');
                fw.append("LogTime");
                fw.append(',');
                fw.append('\n');
                fw.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
    }
}.start();
```

[image: View in Desktop]
[image: Screenshot of Galaxy Nexus]

Comment: How are you sure the folder and file are created?

Comment: In my phone, I have installed an app called ASTORO File Manager, therefore I use it to check my SD Card Usage, the folder is there and the file is in the folder also

Comment: Are you checking within `/emmc` from your desktop?

Comment: what does you mean about /emmc, sorry, I am still a beginning developer, so I am not sure what does you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify append mode, to true,else you will not be able to append to file!

[FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), so in your case it will be,

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(record,true);
```

Comment: ya, I understand if I want to append data in my file, I need to specify the second parameter, I will add it back when I continue the development after I have successfully tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your device to your computer the SD card might not be available to apps if it's in `USB-storage` mode.

Check if you see the SD card content in your computer, if you do, you will not be able to access it from the app.

You should be able to control the SD card mode via a notification called "USB connected" which will allow you to turn `USB storage` on/off.

Your app should prepare for this event and check if the SD card is properly mounted before accessing it:

```
if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: actually, I can see other folders which are not created by my app in the same directory, so I think I can see the SD card content in the computer, maybe I can add the screen shot, then it can make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using file explorer in eclipse to find the file, the path of sdcard folder in file explorer is "/mnt/sdcard".

Comment: in fact, I think I am in sdcard directory when I am exploring the device via the desktop, and I have checked in the phone by the app I mentoned above, the folder and file are existing in both /mnt/sdcard and storage/sdcard0 folders

Comment: Then the "internal storage" folder your screenshot shows and /mnt/sdcard must not be the save folder.

Comment: then may I ask where should I put the folder and file so that I can access it easily when connecting to the desktop?